# Is there a way to specify that JAXB should only print an attribute if it doesn't have a specific value?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am working with JAXB to marshal and unmarshal a java class.

This is the xml I'm looking for:

```
<tag name="example" attribute1="enumValue"/>
```

if attribute1 is set to the default value, I don't want that attribute to print at all, so it would look like this:

```
<tag name="example"/>
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

Right now I have a getter/setter pair that looks like this:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="attribute1")
public EnumExample getEnumExample() {
    return this.enumExample;
}

public void setEnumExample(final EnumExample enumExample) {
    this.enumExample = enumExample;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case:

**XmlAdapter (Attribute1Adapter)**

You could leverage the fact that JAXB will not marshal null attribute values and use an `XmlAdapter` to adjust the value being marshalled to XML.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import forum16972549.Tag.Foo;

public class Attribute1Adapter extends XmlAdapter<Tag.Foo, Tag.Foo>{

    @Override
    public Foo unmarshal(Foo v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Foo marshal(Foo v) throws Exception {
        if(v == Foo.A) {
            return null;
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

**Domain Model (Tag)**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to associate the `XmlAdapter`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tag {

    enum Foo {A, B};

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Attribute1Adapter.class)
    private Foo attribute1;

    public Foo getAttribute1() {
        return attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute1(Foo attribute1) {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code you can use to prove that everything works.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tag.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setAttribute1(Tag.Foo.A);
        System.out.println(tag.getAttribute1());
        marshaller.marshal(tag, System.out);

        tag.setAttribute1(Tag.Foo.B);
        System.out.println(tag.getAttribute1());
        marshaller.marshal(tag, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```xml
A
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tag/>
B
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tag attribute1="B"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Tag**

You could leverage the fact that JAXB will not marshal null attribute values and add some logic to your properties and then use JAXB to map to the field.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tag {

    private static Foo ATTRIBUTE1_DEFAULT = Foo.A;

    enum Foo {A, B};

    @XmlAttribute
    private Foo attribute1;

    public Foo getAttribute1() {
        if(null == attribute1) {
            return ATTRIBUTE1_DEFAULT;
        }
        return attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute1(Foo attribute1) {
        if(ATTRIBUTE1_DEFAULT == attribute1) {
            this.attribute1 = null;
        } else {
            this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        }
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tag.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setAttribute1(Tag.Foo.A);
        System.out.println(tag.getAttribute1());
        marshaller.marshal(tag, System.out);

        tag.setAttribute1(Tag.Foo.B);
        System.out.println(tag.getAttribute1());
        marshaller.marshal(tag, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
A
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tag/>
B
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tag attribute1="B"/>
```

Comment: This looks right, but what happens on the Unmarshalling side? In my version of this solution, if the attribute isn't in the xml, the getter/setter is never called, so it's not set to the default value.

Comment: @chama - In this example the getter will return the default value if the field is null.

Comment: I just tried unmarshalling your code and it worked properly. Must be something with my implementation. Hmmm...

Comment: I think I see my problem. I don't want the attribute to actually be null - it should be the default value. It should just print as null. Does that make sense?

Comment: @chama - With this approach the field would be null, but if you always used the corresponding get method you would see the correct value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that is good enough in my situation.

Comment: @chama - I have added another answer that may work better for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972549/is-there-a-way-to-specify-that-jaxb-should-only-print-an-attribute-if-it-doesnt/16988322#16988322

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible directly using JAXB annotations. But using **required=true** like this,

```
@XmlAttribute(required=true name="attribute1") 
private String enumExample;
```

we can do a workaround. Before calling the setter on that attribute, we can check if the value that will be set is the default value. If yes, we can pass null to that setter and that attribute will not be visible after marshalling.

Comment: Would this solution also work in unmarshalling? If it's a required attribute, there will be an exception if it isn't there, no?